# openNMT translate commands yields garbage results

Tags: python, opennmt

I am running the following command

```
onmt_translate  -model demo-model_step_100000.pt -src data/src-test.txt -output pred.txt -replace_unk -verbose
```

The results in the file 'pred.txt' is something completely different than the source sentences given for translation

The corpus size was 3000 parallel sentences. The preprocess command was -

```
onmt_preprocess -train_src EMMT/01engParallel_onmt.txt -train_tgt EMMT/01maiParallel_onmt.txt -valid_src EMMT/01engValidation_onmt.txt -valid_tgt EMMT/01maiValidation_onmt.txt -save_data EMMT/demo
```

training was on the demo model

```
onmt_train -data EMMT/demo -save_model demo-model
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get decent translations even on "seen" data because:

- Your model got trained on too few sentence pairs (3000 is really too, too few to train a good model). You can only get some more or less meanignful translations with corpora of 4M+ (and the more the better).
- `onmt_train -data EMMT/demo -save_model demo-model` trains a small (2 layers x 500 neurons) unidirectional RNN model (see [documentation](https://opennmt.net/OpenNMT-py/options/train.html)). The `transformer` model type is recommended to obtain state-of-the-art results.

The FAQ says this about how to run a transformer model training:

> The transformer model is very
> sensitive to hyperparameters. To run it effectively you need to set a
> bunch of different options that mimic the Google setup. We have
> confirmed the following command can replicate their WMT results.
>
> ```
> python  train.py -data /tmp/de2/data -save_model /tmp/extra \
>         -layers 6 -rnn_size 512 -word_vec_size 512 -transformer_ff 2048 -heads 8  \
>         -encoder_type transformer -decoder_type transformer -position_encoding \
>         -train_steps 200000  -max_generator_batches 2 -dropout 0.1 \
>         -batch_size 4096 -batch_type tokens -normalization tokens  -accum_count 2 \
>         -optim adam -adam_beta2 0.998 -decay_method noam -warmup_steps 8000 -learning_rate 2 \
>         -max_grad_norm 0 -param_init 0  -param_init_glorot \
>         -label_smoothing 0.1 -valid_steps 10000 -save_checkpoint_steps 10000 \
>         -world_size 4 -gpu_ranks 0 1 2 3
> ```

> Here are what each of the parameters <mean:
>
> `param_init_glorot` `-param_init 0`: correct initialization of parameters
>
> `position_encoding`: add sinusoidal position encoding to each embedding
>
> `optim adam`, `decay_method noam`, `warmup_steps 8000`: use special learning
> rate.
>
> `batch_type tokens`, `normalization tokens`, `accum_count 4`: batch and
> normalize based on number of tokens and not sentences. Compute
> gradients based on four batches.
>
> `label_smoothing 0.1`: use label smoothing loss.

Comment: Thanks. I am now training with 45000 parallel data. The pre-processing goes fine, but the train command fails with "Assertion Error". Here  is my train command -  onmt_train -encoder_type transformer -decoder_type transformer -data EMMT/demo -save_model demo-model

Comment: @girishnjha 45000 is still too few data. Without the full error stack trace, it is impossible to help you more.

Comment: The AssertionError goes away if i remove the encoder/decoder as transformer

Comment: [TransformerEncoderLayer(
  File "C:\Users\Girish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages
\opennmt_py-1.2.0-py3.8.egg\onmt\encoders\transformer.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.self_attn = MultiHeadedAttention(
  File "C:\Users\Girish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages
\opennmt_py-1.2.0-py3.8.egg\onmt\modules\multi_headed_attn.py", line 53, in __in
it__
    assert model_dim % head_count == 0
AssertionError

Comment: this is the result of adding "transformer" as encoder/decoder. Will appreciate any help

Comment: @girishnjha Just see how to run a transformer training [here](https://opennmt.net/OpenNMT-py/FAQ.html#how-do-i-use-the-transformer-model). Again, 45K sentence pair corpus is **too small**. You will only be able to get good results with 4 **million** and more.

Comment: Hi I am training  on a workstation with windows 10 and a AMD GPU. Getting the following error  File "C:\Users\ritu\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\opennmt_py-1.2.0-py3.8.egg\onmt\bin\train.py", line 161, in __init__
    signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, self.signal_handler)
AttributeError: module 'signal' has no attribute 'SIGUSR1'

Comment: My train command now is - onmt_train -data EMMT/demo -save_model  demo-model -layers 6 -rnn_size 512 -word_vec_size 512 -transformer_ff 2048 -heads 8  -encoder_type transformer -decoder_type transformer -position_encoding -train_steps 200000  -max_generator_batches 2 -dropout 0.1 -batch_size 4096 -batch_type tokens -normalization tokens  -accum_count 2 -optim adam -adam_beta2 0.998 -decay_method noam -warmup_steps 8000 -learning_rate 2 -max_grad_norm 0 -param_init 0  -param_init_glorot -label_smoothing 0.1 -valid_steps 10000 -save_checkpoint_steps 10000 -world_size 4 -gpu_ranks 0 1 2 3

Comment: @girishnjha I am not sure if 1) ONMT-py can work in Windows, 2) you need NVIDIA GPU, from what I know, AMD GPUs usually do not work.